# Someone is editing my question's tags and I disagree with their edit

Tags: discussion, support, tags, editing

[As is suggested by Eliah Kagan](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3430/186134);

> **In general**, if you believe your question is de-tagged wrongly, here are some options at your disposal:
>
> - Read the tag's tag wiki and see what other questions are tagged with it. This can sometimes help in figuring out whether or not a tag is appropriate for your question.

[How to remove ccp when installed from binary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722977/how-to-find-the-package-name-and-uninstall-it-in-ubuntu)
  [How can I uninstall popcorn time from Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722631/how-can-i-uninstall-popcorn-time-from-ubuntu-14-04)
  [Uninstalled app still showing icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721832/uninstalled-app-still-showing-icon)
  [Help to UNINSTALL Photoshop. Please, help the Linux newbie)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719910/help-to-uninstall-photoshop-please-help-the-linux-newbie)

and as Briaam thinks the above are rubbish questions, here are all questions with 25+ votes tagged [uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall):

[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)
[How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)
[How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)
[How to uninstall NetBeans?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76908/how-to-uninstall-netbeans)
[How to completely uninstall Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)
[What is the Difference Between `apt-get purge` and `apt-get remove`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove)
[If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)
[Uninstall a program installed with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine)
[Is it possible to undo an apt-get install command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247549/is-it-possible-to-undo-an-apt-get-install-command)
[How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)
[How to uninstall Google Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67047/how-to-uninstall-google-chrome)
[How to remove xubuntu-desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92084/how-to-remove-xubuntu-desktop)
[How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software)
[How do I remove Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217872/how-do-i-remove-steam)
[Remove documentation to save hard drive space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129566/remove-documentation-to-save-hard-drive-space)
[How to remove the graphical user interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196603/how-to-remove-the-graphical-user-interface)
[How do I remove the LAMP stack so I can start over?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over)

They seem to be similar to [Could I remove apt with apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722102/could-i-remove-apt-with-apt)

> - Search meta, to see if the tag is under consideration for removal, or otherwise under discussion.

It has a post here http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14103/discussion-about-tag-uninstall from 7 months ago with lowish views and no consensus.

The suggestions it makes have not been implemented (changing the wiki) and there has been no discussion, despite the tag.

> - Similarly, if you are *sure* the editor removed it based on a subjective judgment, you may add it back (but don't get into an editing/rolling-back war - if it's re-removed again, use a different option). In the case of a tag that has few or no other questions, you should probably not do this, as the intention of the editor may be to get rid of the tag. That's not always right, but should usually be discussed.

I added it back in (rolled back) as there was no edit summary. At the same time I @pinged the user to ask them and they linked in a comment (since removed) to the meta discussion above.

They removed it again, so I left it - not wanting to have an edit war.

> - **Ask a specific question on meta**, about whether or not the tag should really have been removed. That's what this question was taken to be about (in comments). This is usually the best way. If in doubt, this is probably the best thing to do.

Doing this now!

> - Ping the user in chat. For example, to ping me in chat, go into the general chat room, and post a short message with @EliahKagan in it. Even if the user isn't in chat, they will be notified (though it may take some time and you shouldn't expect them to reply immediately). Then you can ask them about the tag removal. You should avoid pinging repeatedly, and remember that meta is often a better place to post, because you can solicit community consensus here.
>
>   - **One caveat:** The user will only be pinged by the chat "bot" if he/she has logged in to chat within *three days or less*.

The user was unresponsive to my arguments in the comments, I feel chat would be unconducive to a good discussion - hence this post.

---

So, my arguments:

1. The tag was removed, not replaced. If the tag had been *replaced* with the specific one, I could understand it, but it was simply removed.
2. The meta post was hardly conclusive

   - There was minimal discussion (one comment) and it has low views.
   - The suggestions (blacklist the tag and / or change the wiki were not done)
3. A lack of revision comment (just the link to the meta post he commented would suffice) is quite frustrating.

Their arguments:

1. The meta post shows agreement based on the 10 upvotes - they're "following community guidance".
2. Tags are ["means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories."](https://askubuntu.com/help/tagging) - this argument falls down as the "more specific" tag was not added to the post.
3. Maybe another I'm missing?

The comments (theirs have been removed):

[image]

and [the revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/722102/revisions).

What should this question be tagged with, and is this the appropriate way to handle the situation?

Comment: 3 out the 4 examples are being closed. Are you *sure* you want to use those? (I'm afraid that the one with "newbie" in the title will rot my eyes, so I decided not to open it).

Comment: @Braiam 2/3 are being closed as duplicates. And oh look: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software   tagged, [tag:uninstall].

Comment: I'm not going to open that question, because I don't have close votes. BTW, I don't agree with none of the duplicates either.

Comment: @Braiam Of course you don't agree.

Comment: @Braiam I've added another load of questions. Are they okay?

Comment: [That question has been more unhelpful than helpful](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers?PostId=1143)

Comment: @Braiam How does a random SEDE query that returns some unexplained numbers make a case? What is that showing? What does "anonymous feedback" mean? It has 32 up and 0 down - that's called positive feedback tbw

Comment: I'm not sure why are you picking the oldest ones, pick the newest! ([unclear](http://askubuntu.com/q/723071/), [not even related](http://askubuntu.com/q/721184), [this is a duplicated of a grub question](http://askubuntu.com/q/721153), [this is a "do a back up!"](http://askubuntu.com/q/721036).

Comment: @Braiam I'm picking all questions with a score of 25 or more. I don't get your issue here - any question related to it is bad, any close vote is wrong and you can make random SEDE queries to prove it? Bravo...?

Comment: So a popular (relatively) tag has lots of mediocre and bad questions. Duh. Common themes are going to have the most bad stuff. Take a look at frequent: http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/uninstall?sort=frequent&pageSize=50